# How to not dismiss the keyboard when the showMenu method invoke in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have ComposePage have a TextField and action button, when press the button show menu,but I not hope to dismiss the keyboard,In flutter how to do this!

Comment: Can you share the code when showing the menu?

Answer (score -1):

add this code in `onPress` function.

```
FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
```

Comment: NOT to dismiss, but you code just requested focus to the fake node